# Como usar el $_GET['']?

Tags: php, get, paginacion

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en php donde estoy usando el id de un producto (?id) y aparte su paginación (?p) pero al hacer el `$_GET['p']` no me sale nada pero si hago `$_GET['id']`me sale por ejemplo `1?p=1`, como le hago para separarlos?, y haci cuando haga  `$_GET['p']` me salga `1`

La url es: **producto.php?id=1?p=1**

Comment: Cual es la url?

Answer (score 1):

La **URL** debe tener este formato.

```
producto.php?id=1&p=1
```

El **andpersand &** sirve para especificar más de un parámetro

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` Es un array asociativo (clave-valor) que permite recopilar todas las variables pasadas por dicho verbo al archivo que se ejecuta.

Al igual que `$_GET` existe `$_POST`, que se encargará tal como lo indica su nombre de recopilar las variables que se pasan por el verbo post. Finalmente está `$_REQUEST` que te permitirá acceder a las variables que se pasen por los verbos get y post.

**¿Cómo le paso variables a mi archivo?**

Todas las variables que se pasen por el verbo GET irán en la url con el siguiente formato:

`url.com/un_archivo.php?var1=hola&var2=chao`

Las variables por post no van puestas en la URL, pero puedes conocer más sobre [métodos de petición HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

**¿Cómo accedo a las variables?**

Lo primero es identificar el verbo HTTP por donde está llegando la variable, si la estás enviando por post, la variable no existirá en $_GET y viceversa.

Si estás enviando una variable por get, puedes obtenerla de la siguiente manera:

`$_GET['nombre_de_tu_variable']`

**Depuración**

Puedes hacer un `print_r();` de `$_GET`, `$_POST` y `$_REQUEST` para ver que variables te están llegando.

EJ:

`print_r($_GET);`

**Buena practica**

Si accedes directamente a una clave del array puede que en ocasiones esta no exista o tu quieras aplicar algunas validaciones...
El error más comun al acceder a estas variables es `Warning: Undefined array key`, que en otras palabras quiere decir que no se encuentra la variable.

Para definir un valor por defecto puedes usar:

```
$algo = isset($_GET['algo']) ? $_GET['algo'] : 'algún valor por defecto';
```

y si estás con php sobre la versión 7 puedes utilizar el nuevo operador [null coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

```
$algo = $_GET['algo'] ?? 'algún valor por defecto';
```